# How to create a regex contains any characters, integers and symbols inside curly braces?

Tags: python, regex

For example, I have strings like these, there could be any characters between two opening and closing curly braces. So, what could be  the regex for these examples?

```
{{.registry}}
{{ if de .proxy ""  }}
{{ end -}}
{{.test_client}}
```

I was trying this, but it´s not working.

```
/{{([^}]*)}}/
```

Comment: How is the above pattern not working? [It works](https://regex101.com/r/WyDmBv/1). However, this question has been asked so many times, I added three sample duplicate links.

Comment: Python doesn't use slashes around regular expressions. If that's literally what you put in a string and passed to `re.findall()` or similar, you are looking for braces immediately inside a pair of literal slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take the lazy star as in

```
{{(.*?)}}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/j0CVzv/1).
Honestly, for your given example strings, your expression works equally well, albeit without the slashes, see [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/j0CVzv/2).

---

So, in `Python` you could use

```
import re

inp = """{{.registry}}
{{ if de .proxy ""  }}
{{ end -}}
{{.test_client}}"""

rx = re.compile(r'{{(.*?)}}')
matches = rx.findall(inp)
print(matches)
```

Which yields (whitespaces intended):

```
['.registry', ' if de .proxy ""  ', ' end -', '.test_client']
```